# Table of calories

Tags: calories

Is there any available table of calories per food type which can be used directly?

I know there are several applications and websites, but everyone of them I found (including Google) only let you search for a specific food, or list a specific category.

I cannot find a simple list (database, Excel sheet, CSV, whatever) with all the information readily accessible, so that I could e.g. sort by calorie count, randomly pick ingredients for my next meal, or do whatever it pleases me.

I know most applications protect their data, but I was expecting to find at least a few available datasets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download [the USDA list of nutrient information](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=24912), which is quite extensive. I don't know the exact license, but being a publication of the US government, it might well be public domain, you'll have to research this. I assume it's at least OK for personal use, after all they let you download it. There are several formats available to choose from.

Comment: Per section 105 of the Copyright Act, [copyright status of work done by an officer or employee of the federal government is not entitled to domestic copyright protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_status_of_work_by_the_U.S._government), and is therefore ok to consider as public domain - except for certain signs and logos, which are likely trademarked and under that protection. Additionally, this only applies to US domestic, not abroad (in which the US gov't can hold copyright on that content if it so chooses to apply)